# My web page redirects to a blank screen on submitting the form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to display a flash message saying 'Mail sent' on sending an email from a form in cakephp. The email is send successfully to the recipient but then it goes to a blank screen and doesn't display the flash message which indicates that the message has been sent.I have checked for spaces before and after php tags in the controller and that doesnt seem to be the problem.IT works fine on my localhost and displays the message but not on the server.I will put my controller code

```
public function contact() {

    $email = new CakeEmail();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Contact->set($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {
            //$this->Project->set($this->data)
            $name = $this->request->data['Contact']['name'];
            $mail = $this->request->data['Contact']['email'];
            $email->from(array($mail => $name));
            $email->to('sales@blacknova.com.au');
            if (isset($this->request->data['Contact']['contacttime'])) {
                $ctime = implode(',', $this->request->data['Contact']['contacttime']);
            }
            $message = "Phone No : ".$this->request->data['Contact']['phone']."\n\nBest Contact time :".$ctime." \n\nMessage : ".$this->request->data['Contact']['description'];
            $email->subject('BlackNova Website Contact Form Message');
            //$email->send($message);
            //$success =1;
            //$email->send($this->request->data['Contact']['phone']);
            //pr($message);
            if ($email->send($message)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Mail sent successfully');
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'BlockContents', 'action' => 'contact'));
                //pr($success);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a contact.ctp

```
    <div id="formcontainer_left">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Contact'); ?> 
    <div class="inputbox1"><?php echo $this->Form->input('name');?></div><br>
    <div class="inputbox2"><?php echo $this->Form->input('email'); ?></div><br>
    <div class="inputbox3"><?php echo $this->Form->input('phone');?></div><br>
    </div>
    <div id="formcontainer_right">  
    <div id="me"><?php echo $this->Form->input('description');?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('SUBMIT');?>

    </div>

      <div  id="formcontainer_xright">

    <div class="formcontainer_last"> BEST TIME TO CONTACT* </div>
    <div id="chkbox">
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('contacttime',array('label'=>false,'type'=>'select','class'=>'checkdiv','multiple'=>'checkbox','options'=>array('Before work' =>'Before work','During work'=>'During work','After work'=>'After work'),'escape'=>false)) ;?> 
    </div>
      </div>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
        <div class="contactformbottom">
    </div>

</div> 

<div id="formcontainer2">
   <p> <?php echo $this->Session->flash();?></p>
```

Could somebody please help me find out why it happens only on the srver and not on the local host?

Comment: The debug value on conf is the same in localhost and the server?

Comment: yes, it is set to config:write('debug',2) on both local host and server

Comment: The blank screen with debug > 0 means that there's an error (and cake doesn't redirects automatically). Try setting debug to 3 and see if something shows up on the white screen. Otherwise set it to 0 on the server and that should bypass the blank screen. Is the contact action in your BlockContents controller? If so, why the redirect after the flash message if it's the same screen? What happens when you comment that redirect?

Comment: I put debug to 3 but of no use.I set it to 0 on the server but still showing the blank screen.If I don't do a redirect to the same page, it doesn't clear my form boxes .

Comment: IT is the redirect action which causes the problem cause when i comment that out the page shows up without clearing the values in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `BlockContents` isn't a valid controller in the redirect url.

If you try using an underscored version `block_contents` instead, you'll find it'll probably work.

Take a look at the recommended usage in the book. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#url-considerations-for-controller-names

Comment: So I will have to replace the entire code with block_contents i guess..I havent tried it cause that will be  alot of changes to my live website

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidYell says, the problem is the controller in the redirect. If you do need that redirect, his answer should solve everything. I just want to point out you don't really need the redirect if all you want is to clear the values in the textboxes but stay on the same action.

```
if ($email->send($message)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Mail sent successfully');
    $this->request->data = null;
}
```

should clear the textboxes with no need of redirection.

Comment: Thanks, it clears the text boxes but  doesn't display any flash messages

Comment: Try this in the view `<?php echo $this->Session->flash('flash');?>`, and also, check with firebug or the like the resulting html and see if the place where the flash message is supposed to be is actually there but with a `display:none` style or something like that (happened to me sometimes).